# Substantial performance decrease when using display: flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a table with 3880 table rows of the following syntax:

```html
<tr class="netflixDataResult" active="no">html</tr>
```

I have added event listeners to all of those, when one is clicked its state is changed to active:

```html
<tr class="netflixDataResult" active="yes">html</tr>
```

this means the following CSS will activate:

```css
.netflixDataResult[active="yes"]{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

When it's unhovered its state is changed back to inactive:

```css
#displayNetflixData thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.netflixDataResult {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    /* box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1); */
}
```

Now I have a different JS function that just moves UI some stuff around, importantly it changes the position and height of the table with 3,880 rows.

It does this fine normally, however when one or more of those table rows have been changed to active and back to unactive *and then* that JS function is triggered the entire website just frame drops/lags.

If I comment out the `display: flex`, it doesn't frame drop:

```css
.netflixDataResult[active="yes"]{
    /* display: flex; */
    padding: 2px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Why? I would like to use `display: flex;` if possible; any workarounds?

Comment: Changing the display type of a table is generally discouraged. You used a table for a reason so switching to flexbox is not logical. If you want the advantages of flexbox use divs etc not a table.

Comment: I'd also question the wisdom of a table that long. It's rarely good UX.